# Is it possible to import Alexa Skill to Cortana?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I have two skills on Alexa and am planning to have those same skills on Cortana. However, I'm not sure if it is possible to import the Alexa skills with a tool to Cortana and launch them there. Or do I need to redevelop those skills for Cortana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS I know, MS plans to integrate Cortana and Alexa. So you may talk to cortana to use Alexa skill in the future.
https://www.theverge.com/2017/8/30/16224876/microsoft-amazon-cortana-alexa-partnership